# minimum cost to connect all matrix cells in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, data-structures

i have matrix for example as below:

```
 int M[][]=  new int[][] {   {-1,-1, X, X, X},
                             {X ,-1, X, X,-1},
                             {-1, X, X,-1,-1},
                             {X , X, X, X, X},
                             {-1, X,-1, X,-1}
                         };
```

let's assume that we want to connect all matrix cells with value -1.Here X has some value that may be different for all cells. We can say -1 is connected if any of the adjacent neighbor is -1. So to connect all -1 we have to make X to -1. but this has some cost and that will be the value of X.

So what will be the minimum cost to connect all -1.

So some one can please suggest me what algorithm we can use and how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It's a classical search problem.

Read a book/Article about different search algorithms and decide which suits your need. ( Take easiest for you to implement if speed does not really matter).

Here are some candidates you may consider:

- depth first search
- breath first search
- A*search

All of them will find the cheapest solution but runtime and memory usage might differ a lot.

For all of them you can find all needed information about advantages/disadvantages, pseudo code and everything you need at wikipedia.

Comment: well, you're not quite right. This is the problem of finding a minimum-spanning-tree, not of finding the shortest path.

Comment: @Paul: The search algorithms I mentioned in my answer can be used to solve any search problem with finite number of choices in each step. So you can use them to find a minimum-spanning-tree (even if there are faster specific algorithms for this problem) and also to find a shortest path as well as solving a lot of other search problems.

Comment: So you want to search the solution to the problem using DFS or any other algo? Well, that would work, but it's quite inefficient compared to minimum-spanning-tree algos and you didn't exactly make that clear in the answer.

Comment: @Paul: I'm not sure if it will be so simple to generate all the possible edges of the multi graph in which you could than run a minimum-spanning-tree algo. But there are a lot of possible edges to be generated for the graph between the -1 isles. So if the matrix is small, why not go for the a simple search?